# pass string by pointer in CPP and getting unexpected output

Tags: c++

I tried this code and I can not understand why I get the output as "HL" instead of "Hl".
Someone please explain.

```
void t(string *s){
    s[1]='l';
}
int main(){
    string s = "HL";
    t(&s);
    cout<<s;
}
```

Comment: Title says pass by reference, code passes by pointer. Please update your title.

Comment: you SHOULD pass the string by reference, `void t(string& s)`, then just call `t(s)` to modify the string. the answers below are perfectly correct and tell you what's happening.

Comment: You're expecting `s[1]` to dereference twice, once to get from a pointer to the string and a second time to get from the string to its second element. You want `s[0][1]` or `(*s)[1]` or something like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have now is updating a non existing string by setting it equal to `'l'`. This is  undefined behavior.

The reason this is failing is you're indexing the pointer as if it was pointing to an array of string (when it is in fact pointing to a single string). What you meant to do was to index the actual string to get it's character. You must first dereference the pointer like so:

```
void t(string *s){
    (*s)[1]='l';
}
int main(){
    string s = "HL";
    t(&s);
    cout<<s;
}
```

[See live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/144bcc9f77d3a904)

If you were actually using references, like your title suggested, you wouldn't need to do anything special syntax wise:

```
void t(string& s){
    s[1]='l';
}
int main(){
    string s = "HL";
    t(s);
    cout<<s;
}
```

[See live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b2ba116106cffe45)

Answer (score 2):

In the function `t`, `s` is a `string*` and hence `s[1]` is equivalent to `*(s+1)`. ITW, it is being treated as a pointer to the beginning of an array of `string`s and the element with index `1` is being set to `"l"`. Change your code to `(*s)[1] = 'l';` to do what you intended.